# How can we remove duplicate records from postgres while writing into postgres using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am scheduling my spark job(writing into postgresdb) using airflow, facing the issue of duplicate records while writing. How can I avoid duplicates?

```
 query.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", URL) \
.option("dbtable", "tagpool_tag_raw") \
.option("user", USER) \
.option("password", PW) \
.option("driver", DRIVER) \
.save(mode='append')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `dropDuplicates()` before write.

```
query.dropDuplicates() \
.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", URL) \
.option("dbtable", "tagpool_tag_raw") \
.option("user", USER) \
.option("password", PW) \
.option("driver", DRIVER) \
.save(mode='append')
```